# Question about style in ConTeXt

Tags: context

guys am working on a document and i really want to recreate the page number and the footer styles of this [document](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code.

Comment: Have a look at the [source](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/src/3eb2d078f0023266585aec42d98326d72567b9d6/doc/context/sources/general/manuals/languages/languages-environment.tex) to [languages-mkiv.pdf](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/raw/3eb2d078f0023266585aec42d98326d72567b9d6/doc/context/documents/general/manuals/languages-mkiv.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

As commented, you can simply copy-paste the code for [`languages-mkiv.pdf`](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/src/3eb2d078f0023266585aec42d98326d72567b9d6/doc/context/sources/general/manuals/languages/languages-environment.tex).

```
\defineoverlay
  [page]
  [\useMPgraphic{page}]

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background=page]

\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided,
   location=]

\definecolor[maincolor][darkgray]

\startuseMPgraphic{page}

    StartPage ;

        linecap := butt ;

        if OnRightPage :

            path p ; p := (
                urcorner Page shifted (-2cm,0) --
                urcorner Page                  --
                urcorner Page shifted (0,-2cm) -- cycle
            ) shifted (-2.5mm,-2.5mm) ;

        else :

            path p ; p := (
                ulcorner Page shifted (2cm,0)  --
                ulcorner Page                  --
                ulcorner Page shifted (0,-2cm) -- cycle
            ) shifted (2.5mm,-2.5mm) ;

        fi ;

        fill p
            withpen pencircle scaled 1mm
            withcolor \MPcolor{maincolor} ;

        draw thetextext("\bf\userpagenumber",
            if OnRightPage : urcorner p shifted (-5mm,-5mm) else : ulcorner p shifted (5mm,-5mm) fi)
            withcolor white ;

        if OnRightPage :

            path p ; p := (
                lrcorner Page shifted (-5cm,0) --
                lrcorner Page
            ) shifted (-5mm,10mm)

        else :

            path p ; p := (
                llcorner Page shifted (5cm,0) --
                llcorner Page
            ) shifted (5mm,10mm) ;

        fi ;

        draw p
            withpen pencircle scaled 1mm
            withcolor \MPcolor{maincolor} ;

        draw if OnRightPage :
            thetextext.lft("\bf\getspecificstructuretitle{chapter}",lrcorner Page shifted (-5mm,5mm))
        else :
            thetextext.rt ("\bf\getspecificstructuretitle{chapter}",llcorner Page shifted ( 5mm,5mm))
     %  fi withcolor \MPcolor{\namedstructureuservariable{chapter}{color}} ;
        fi withcolor \MPcolor{maincolor} ;

    StopPage ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\starttext

\startchapter[title=Example 1]
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Example 2]
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=Example 3]
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]